# Azure Mobile App backend with SSL

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

How can I enable SSL for Azure Mobile App backend hosted on local IIS? When I enable SSL in project properties, the requests like https://localhost:443/tables/todo does not return any response (it works for normal http request). Should I enable it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling SSL for a local IIS instance for mobile apps is just the same as enabling SSL for a local IIS instance for any other app.  There is nothing special about the mobile app in this respect.

This is my go-to reference: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/587443/how-to-create-ssl-secure-server-https-in-local-iis